# Probability of drawing 4 balls from an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 8 red balls and 8 blue balls, shuffled randomly. Draw 4 balls without replacement, what is the probability that you draw the same number of red and blue balls?

I came up with the following solutions:
My sample space would be to arrange this 16 balls in 16 choose 8 way.
Then assume equally likely outcome and count the cases where the event of interest happen, which is 4 choose 2 to arrange 2 red and 2 blue balls among the first 4, then times 12 choose 6 ways to arrange the remaining 12 balls.

However, I also write the following program to verify my answer

```
from itertools import combinations
def first_four(list_ball):
    for i in list_ball:
        count = 0
        for j in range(0,4):
            if list_ball[j] == 'R':
               count = count + 1
            else:
               count = count - 1
        if count == 0:
           return True
        else:
           return False

list_ball = ['R','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','B',
         'B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
count = 0
total = 0
for c in combinations(list_ball, 4):
    total = total + 1
    if first_four(c) == True:
        count = count + 1
print count / total
```

But clearly the two methods give different answer, where is it that I have done wrong? Sorry I don't know how to write formula in mathematics, I know LaTeX but I can't seem to get it work in here.

**Turns out I am using a different model of counting, and both answers are correct! Problem solved, thanks!**

Comment: Regarding the math, it should be$\binom{8}{4}/\binom{16}{4} = \frac{1}{26}$ in case that is the source of your problems. Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme  In the comments on my answer, lplouis explained that he or she was counting selections of all $16$ balls in which exactly two of the first four balls selected were red.  The answer $$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{16}{12}}{\binom{16}{8}}$$ lplouis obtained is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see, I see. I misread the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are drawing four balls from the urn, you draw the same number of red balls and blue balls when you draw two of each.  Since there are eight red balls and eight blue balls in the urn, the number of ways we can do this is $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{8}{2}$$  The number of ways we can draw four of the sixteen balls in the urn is $$\binom{16}{4}$$ 
Thus, the probability of drawing the same number of red balls and blue balls is 
$$\frac{\binom{8}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{16}{4}}$$

Comment: can you tell me why my way of counting is wrong?

Comment: @lplouis  I have updated my answer to attempt an analysis of your errors.  That said, some of what I wrote is mere guesswork.

Comment: I calculated 16 choose 8 because I want to list out all the possible combination of the arrangement of the 16 balls(without order) Then, when the first 4 have the same number of red and blue, the remaining 12 balls can be arranged in 12 choose 6 ways

Comment: Your answer is correct.  The explanation you just wrote in your comment is much clearer than what you wrote in your question.  I would only add that you counted selections of all $16$ balls in which exactly two of the first four balls selected were red.

Comment: But the probability calculated in my way is not equal to your solution

Comment: And I think that your answer actually think that all the balls are distinguishable?

Comment: @lplouis  The balls are indistinguishable except by color in my solution.  Moreover, your method, my method, and that of vrugtehagel all yield the answer $\frac{28}{65}$.

Comment: Right, but I still think that your way of counting implies that the balls are distinguishable while their order of selection doesn't matter. 16 choose 4 means that out of 16 distinguishable objects you choose 4 out.

Comment: My denominator represents the number of ways of making an unordered selection of four of the sixteen balls of any color in the urn.  My numerator represents the number of ways of making an unordered selection of two of the eight red balls and two of the eight blue balls in the urn.

Comment: Yes, it is unordered, but you are implicitly naming them R1 R2 R3 ......R8. Think about this, if I have 2 red balls and 2 blue balls. This time you are not to count probability, but rather, you are to count the number of different outcome of drawing one ball from the urn. Clearly it is 2. But in your way, you will count 4 choose 1. But note in terms of probability, whether counting as indistinguishable or distinguishable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The chance that the first ball is blue, is $\frac{8}{16}$. The chance that the second ball is blue, is $\frac{7}{15}$. The chance that the other two balls are both red, is $\frac{8}{14}\frac{7}{13}$. Thus, the total chance that the first two are blue and the second two red, is $\frac{8}{16}\frac{7}{15}\frac{8}{14}\frac{7}{13}=\frac{3136}{43680}=\frac{14}{195}$. Since we shouldn't take the order of the balls into account, we should multiply by 6, for there are 6 different orders we can get 2 blue and 2 red balls. So the final outcome is $\frac{28}{65}$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: But can you do this in a counting way? Or point out where is it that I went wrong?

Comment: I'd edit my answer, but N. F. Taussig added your request as an answer already

Answer (score 0):

> ... and count the cases where the event of interest happen, which is 4
>   choose 2 to arrange 2 red and 2 blue balls, then times 12 choose 6.

Your event of interest is "8 choose 2 - to pick two (red) balls and 8 choose 2 - to pick two (blue) balls".